# What is the correct spelling of narcoject/narcojet?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, medicine-and-drugs

In the Shadowrun Fifth Edition Core Rulebook, there are two different spellings used to refer to a tranquilliser in the game: "narcoject", and "narcojet". I am assuming that the former spelling is the correct one given that it's used most commonly throughout the book (pages 6, 410, 430, and 471) whereas the latter spelling only can be found in one instance (page 409). However, I'd still like to know, has any official correction been issued regarding this? What does other official Shadowrun media say?

Comment: @Jack Why did you change tranquilliser to tranquillizer? Is there some rule/convention saying that US English is preferred here?

Comment: Nope - [as long as it's a valid spelling, we defer to the author's preference](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/33569) (except maybe if it's a game term with a particular spelling, in which case we tend to prefer the spelling used in the game being asked about).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The correct spelling is "narcoject"

As you note, this is the most common spelling, including the one used twice in the item description on p. 410, which suggests that the spelling in the table on p. 409 is the typo. There's no mention of this in any official errata documents (which isn't a surprise, given the state of errata for SR5), although it's possible it was quietly fixed in a later printing (it wasn't as of the 3rd printing, which I have in front of me).

We can also look back to previous editions, starting with 1st edition, which first invented the drug and can be considered the authoritative source: it spells it "narcoject" (twice) in the item description on p. 147 of the core rulebook. The spelling remains consistent in every following core rulebook: 2nd edition (p. 277), 3rd edition (p. 250), and 4th edition (p. 246).